# How to always use the newest version of a Docker Base Image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a DockerFile, for example, that contains the following line to pull the base image:

```
FROM myHub.com/base-image
```

I'm not specifying which tag to use. Now, let's say a newer image of `base-image` is pushed into the hub (version 2). If I run `docker build` again, docker figures  out that my local system already has the base image pulled, so it uses the cache and keeps (version 1).

A quick fix is for me to specify the tag:

```
FROM myHub.com/base-image:2.0
```

But that doesn't seem very efficient. Because when a newer version is pushed again, I will have to manually change the tag in my dockerfile. Is there a better way to handle this? I'm new to Docker so there is quite a bit I'm unfamiliar with. Thanks

Comment: docker build --pull

Comment: @AnthonySottile during some research I saw the --pull flag as an option. But any downsides to that? I think there's quite a bit of overhead in always pulling and ignoring the cache. It would be nice if we can tell Docker (pull if the cache doesn't have the latest version). Also, I read that docker run doesn't have the --pull option. So after I build the image and do docker run, will it still use the old version?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer more sophisticated than running `docker pull myHub.com/base-image` before your new build, or can it just solve the problem?

Comment: `--pull` does exactly what you're asking for. Note that a pull when you're up to date is essentially a noop (except it checks the remote registry, which it would have to do anyway). Run will run whatever you tell it to run, so if you built a tag and run it, it will use what you built

Comment: The problem is that if you want to really _always_ pull images before any builds (like in Jenkins) looks like there's no way to do that.

Comment: For example, Terraform supports CLI arguments as environment variables: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/environment-variables.html#tf_cli_args-and-tf_cli_args_name. But Docker doesn't and it makes hard to control that all developers use `--pull` argument.

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55821

Answer (score 9):

solution:

```
docker build --pull
```

explanation:

> `--pull` Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: I'm sorry for being *that* guy who takes a comment and turns it into an answer. But I was finding this question because I entered the exact same question into google, and almost overlooked the comment containing the answer.